# Pre rendered 3d

Tags: unity, rendering

I am so confused on how to create isometric buildings ( like the ones in Clash of clans ) so I can use them in my project in Unity..What I've understood ( I think ) is the buildings are actually 3d models but rendered as 2d images..I have created lots of 3d models in Blender and I want them to look as the ones in the pic.. How can I do this?

[image]

([Image source](https://retrostylegames.com/img/2016/07/sprites-hex-steampower-isometric-pre-rendered-buildings.jpg))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient method to export a lot of pre-rendered sprites from 3D models](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/101831/efficient-method-to-export-a-lot-of-pre-rendered-sprites-from-3d-models)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You render them as a png/preferred image format from the angle you want from your 3d program. Shadows and everything is baked into your sprite. Then in Unity you import them as regular sprites and use that in 2d.

There's not really much more to it. I guess, you have to texture it etc, but that's not something you do in Unity anyway.

Comment: So render them in blender and save them as png?

Comment: Yeah, that's all you need. Obviously there are things you can't do with it that way, like rotate around the buildings or real dynamic lighting, but for an isometric game those are not needed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this site [here](https://design.tutsplus.com/articles/15-illustrator-tutorials-for-creating-isometric-illustrations--vector-5017).

You can do this as 2D images, not 3D models being rendered 2D. They are actually 2D sprites that are just made in such a way with appropriate proportions and tools to make them appear as though they are 3-Dimensional. That's the point of isometric - "having equal dimensions".

The tutorials on that site use Illustrator so if you don't have that and intend to legitimately make these, then it's definitely a great tool to get, but there are free, lower quality, tools that do essentially the same stuff.

Comment: unfortunately I already created the 3d models..I dont want to do them again in Illustrator

Comment: Gotcha - well in that case go along the lines of what Nicki said

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need is orthographic projection. Orthographic projection maintains the distance between points and usually used for generation of minimaps in games. Blender should be able to render pictures with this mode. Please try it and tell if it helped your case